# How do I get Word to change my default number of copies to print?

Tags: microsoft-word

Somehow I changed the default number of copies to print in Word. It's now set to 13, which is like some kind of booby trap for my household. I can change it ever time I print, but every now and then I forget to, and I get 13 copies of a Joel on Software article for reading on the train.

How do I set the default number of copies?

Comment: Which version of Word is this?

Comment: What if you print a page from Notepad? Or what if you use another printer (like [a PDF printer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/))? (Just guessing it's not a default in Word, but a default in your system wide printer preferences. One is administered from Word, the other from Control Panel.)

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Devices and Printers" either from Control Panel or searching in "Windows 7 Start Menu", and right click on your printer and select "Printing Preferences". In the "Advanced" tab, set the default "number of copies" to 1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, and I don't see an option for the default number of copies there.

Comment: I have a "Printing Defaults" button on the Advanced tab (on Vista). The number of copies option is in there. Does 7 have this button?

Comment: Please see the screenies I added.